# Which version of notating dynamics for woodwinds is more clear?

Tags: theory, notation, dynamics, woodwinds

As in title - which is better (if any)? Specifically for flutes and oboes. [image]

Comment: It's quite hard for a woodwind instrument to change dynamic abruptly (while remaining in-tune) without re-articulating, are your sure you don't want a hairpin between the tied notes?

Comment: You say "flutes and woodwinds" - if you have several players you could get the effect you're after by having everyone playing at the start of the bar, and then have most of them stop after the first minim, leaving one or two players.

Comment: Dynamic notation is completely instrument-independent.   And, @ElementsinSpace that's simply not true for even mid-level skilled players.

Comment: The tie might be confusing.  Could you just mark it *legato*?

Comment: @aparente001 From the version in line 1, the OP _wants_ the notes tied. So now, the question is how to notate that without giving the impression of merely wanting it legato....

Comment: @JamesMartin - I guess they could write something like "fully connected."  Or maybe there's a way of notating for woodwinds *not articulalted*?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - agreed on piano, guitar and some others, but flute and oboe?

Comment: Just checking, you don't mean a [sforzando piano](https://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/3112-sforzando_piano), do you? (often played in concert bands by the band en masse, and often followed immediately by a crescendo on the same note).

Comment: @Pam - not quite the same - sf is suddenly loud, whereas f is just loud, loder than the previous note/s, but not sf. And sf/p is usually a short sf, longer p, from experience.

Comment: Are you expecting a diminuendo, or a rearticulation after two beats? That would give you your answer. I would argue the first notation with a clear diminuendo notation would be the most unambiguous, for the former. For the latter, the lower notation is more clear, but definitely not unambiguous.

Comment: @Tim yes agreed, it's unlikely to be quite the same thing, and yes the sfp usually has the shortest possible loud part with an almost immediate change to piano. But since it's a change in dynamic over a single (note?) pitch, I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 11):

No.2 if you want the 'p' to start exactly on the third beat.

Comment: Agree. Version 1 is just plain confusing.

Comment: For any instrument. I would take v 1 to mean literally "change from F to P anywhere within the measure that seems good to you." Or rather would come to that conclusion after scratching my head a long time about whether it was a *fp* with strange spacing, or whether a note was missing, or it was a mistake.

Comment: Yep,  Version 1 is (or should be) illegal.  If you wanted a decrescendo then you'd  annotate  " F [hairpin] P"  .     But in any case it doesn't hurt to write , in version 2,  "F subito P" so that people aren't tempted to perform a decrescendo.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout version 2 is equally confusing.  Is it a tie or a slur?  The performer is likely to conclude that it can't be a tie, because if no articulation is intended it should be a whole note.

Comment: @phoog - wasn't aware that a slur could ever be used between two of the same notes, particularly in the same bar. Therefore it must be a tie, making the dynamics appropriate,

Comment: @Tim Yes absolutely, people write slurs over passages involving repeated notes, to indicate a legato approach or general phrasing. You can even see someone above who has misunderstood v2 in exactly that way, assuming that the OP didn't want a tie and commenting "Could you just mark it legato?". (Not to disagree with you about v2 being better than v1 - but it still could easily be misunderstood.)

Comment: @Tim slurs with notes of the same pitch are common in string writing.  They also occur occasionally in wind parts.  The traditional rules for tying notes call for a whole note/semibreve here.  It's ambiguous, therefore, whether the two half notes/minims were chosen to indicate a subtle rearticulation or the timing of the dynamic shift.  Unless that is clear from the context, I would recommend some additional notation to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are problematic.  The first version, as you noticed, is imprecise as to the timing of the *piano* mark.  The second version could be interpreted as asking for a rearticulation on the second note.

That problem aside, following *forte* with *piano* is ambiguous by itself as it says nothing about the rate of reduction of the volume.  Some interpreters will infer a decrescendo, while others will change suddenly from loud to soft.

It's better, therefore, to be explicit: use a decrescendo wedge or write *sub p,* where *sub* is short for *subito,* which means "suddenly."  (Even this, however, leaves room for interpretation; the underlying problem is that dynamic markings are inherently imprecise, which is one reason why we use the term "interpretation."  One part of learning to be a composer is learning to cede control of your creations to others.)

Traditionally, the timing of dynamic variation within a single long note is given by precise alignment.  If you find that insufficient, you could invent some new notation.  In option 1, you could place little half notes next to the *f* and *p,* or in option two you could add the text "tied" or "without articulation" above the second half note.

Another option might be what copy editors call "recasting": rethink your orchestration.  Revoice the chord in the second half of the measure, having each instrument drop an octave or perhaps just to the next lower pitch, or, as Brian THOMAS suggested in a comment, have some of the instruments drop out in the middle of the measure.

Comment: The *rate* of reduction isn't in question - it comes as soon as the second note is due - looking at the 'p' placement. I feel it's pretty categoric, with little wriggle room for readers. The 'sub' idea is a ood one, re-inforcing what's already being told what to do. A decrescendo it is not - tha would be easily written with a hairpin.

Comment: Are you certain that the composer does not desire a gradual change from _f_ to _p_?  Even if you are, and even if you are correct, not everyone reading this notation would share that certainty.  I mentioned the possibility of an explicit decrescendo in case that was in fact the composer's intention.

Comment: if a gradual change was required, surely a hairpin would suffice - f at the start, p at the end, if absolutely neccessary. It's really up to the composer to be as accurate and clear (or not) as to what he expects readers to play.

Comment: @Tim and a "hairpin" (which I called a "decrescendo wedge" in the answer) is one way of notating a decrescendo explicitly -- and a more precise way than simply using the word, of course. I'm coming at this with memories of long debates in leaderless rehearsals about the specific meaning of notation. Surely you've had similar experiences? You know, 10 people in the room, 9 of whom are convinced that it's definitely _subito,_ the other thinking that there's an implicit decrescendo, and 4 of the 9 thinking that even though it's obviously intended to be _subito,_ composers' dynamics are optional.

Comment: Too many times! That's why it's either me or some other sucker who's the leader - and his word goes, like/lump it. But there's more than a subtle difference between no. 2 and a decrescendo, so there shouldn't even be a discussion - 1st note f, 2nd p., which isn't anywhere near a decrescendo.